# Opencv Findcontours cause heap error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv 2.49.

But I am stuck by find contours function for hours.

When I run the program in debug mode and the error box returns

> Debug assertion failed
>
> Program: ...
>   File f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgheap.c
>
> Line: 1322
>
> Exception:_ CrtIsValidHeapPoionter(pUserData)

And here is my function

```
HRESULT OpenCVHelper::DrawHand(Mat* pImg)        
{
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cvtColor(*pImg, *pImg, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
    //Canny(*pImg, *pImg, 30,50);
    threshold( *pImg, *pImg, 50, 255,THRESH_BINARY);  
    if(pImg->type() == CV_8UC1)
    {
        findContours( *pImg, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
    }
        for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
       {
        Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255),  rng.uniform(0,255) );
        Scalar color( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
        drawContours( *pImg, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
        }

//contours.clear();
//hierarchy.clear();
cvtColor(*pImg, *pImg, CV_GRAY2RGBA);
return S_OK;
```

}

When I remove findcontour function there is no error.

When I use findcontour it pops the error box showed above.

When I add "contours.clear(); hierarchy.clear();" these two lines, there is no error message but the program still crashes.

Anyone can help?

EDIT 1. I find out the allocator for causing heap corruption, which is vector > contours; but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is that the code you're using? What's up with the `color` redefinition?

Comment: @alrikai ahh, sorry, the first line was commented. Ye I'm using this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have should work. Most likely point of failure is having an empty image when you get to findContours. I am not talking about uninitialized image but the one that was initialized with Size(0,0). Change your 'if-statement' to be:

```
if ((pImg->type() == CV_8UC1) && (pImg->rows>0))
```

If this won't help, than next step is to verify that the function that crushes is indeed findContours and not drawContours. The crash may be in drawContours because it is not used when you remove findContours.

Also it is VERY not recommended to use pointer to Mat. Mat is a smart pointer by itself, and it has reference counter. This will create all kinds of nasty bugs.

Comment: It passes the condition (pImg->type() == CV_8UC1) && (pImg->rows>0) but also gives a crash. And the debugger shows the 'accessing violation reading location'

Comment: Well my best guess is that it comes from memory corruption of some sort. And the best candidate to be the cause of corruption is use of pointers to Mat. Make a try without them.

Answer (score 3):

### Finally I found problem...

My Dev Environment
window10 x64, Intel i5 ( X64 ), 
MS Visual Studio 2010 SP1

### OpenCV 2.4.9 ( Test 2.4.13 get the same error)

Some people solve this problem : up to opencv version. 2.4.9.
, Hear is my code.

```
Mat Img = imread( src_image );
if (Img.rows == 0 || Img.cols == 0)
    return -1;

Mat ImgGray;
cvtColor( Img, ImgGray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
Mat threshold_output;
vector<vector<Point>>  contours; // << 
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

int blkSize = 5;
int nKernelSz = 3;
double dFactor = 2.0f;

adaptiveThreshold(ImgGray,threshold_output, 
100,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV,blkSize, 5);

findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, 
CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

---

"vector < vector < Point > > "
  Causes an error on runtime library  /MTd 
 Solve : runtime library change to /MD

This is the site referenced below.
http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/c-interface-heap-mem-problem-findcontours-td7020857.html